# GetTwinAsync() throws serialization casting exception -> DatetimeOffset

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Hi we get this casting error when we tried to get the device twin from IOT hub

`` Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions.IotHubException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' to type 'System.DateTime'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' to type 'System.DateTime'.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared.TwinJsonConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.<ReadResponseMessageAsync>d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<<GetAsync>b__9>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.<ExecuteAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.<ExecuteAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.<GetAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) ``

And we use device SDK,
`_registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
await _registryManager.GetTwinAsync(deviceId);`
I am so far not able to reproduce this from the local, however it is happening in one of our test environment.

Comment: try to update a device SDK for Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared version >= 1.5.0, etc.)

Comment: I do have the version 1.5.0 with Microsft.Azure.devices version 1.6.0

Comment: based on the catch, it failed at "statusUpdateTime" or "lastActivityTime" in the line  = new DateTime?((DateTime) reader.Value);  Do you have this issue on the portal/device twin? Is this happen at all devices? Where is running your RegistryManager?  in the device, cloud, etc.

Comment: If I fetch them using the same code from my local it never fails, but it do fails for all of the devices in the test env. We got a an actor from service fabric which uses the registrymanager to get the device details. And it fails for all the devices. ```"statusUpdateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
    "connectionState": "Connected",
    "lastActivityTime": "2018-06-21T10:39:08.5478442+00:00",``` This is from the iotHub for one of those device

Comment: it's strange, try to use the REST API to get the device twin in the json formatted text. You can use a reflection to obtain a HttpClient and Authorization header from the registryManager object, see this code snippet in my answer for your help and troubleshooting.

Comment: @TBA, which region did you create the IoT Hub for?

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT I have it for east US

Comment: @TBA, have you tried to get the device twin using a REST API as Roman Kiss mentioned in the bad environment? BTW, was the exception thrown in the bad environment for each device or a special device?

Comment: We have't able to push that code to the bad env yet due to some other release procedures and ongoing test cycle. I did call that iothub in my local and was able to get it right. Will be giving an updated build shortly to test this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a while for us to figure out, but check if the default json serializer has configured DateParseHandling to DateTimeOffset.

```
      JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
        };
```

If this is the case, you will have to override the serializer for DeviceTwin as other codemust be depending on this setting.

Comment: Thanks John that was the issue.

Comment: I've created a [PR 538 for Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/pull/538) to use the JSONReader.ReadAsDateTime to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks John I saw that :)

Answer (score 1):

get the device twin using a Rest API from the registryManager:

```
        #region get the device twin

        var finfo = registryManager.GetType().GetField("httpClientHelper", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(registryManager);
        HttpClient client = finfo.GetType().GetField("httpClientObj", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(finfo) as HttpClient;
        var provider = finfo.GetType().GetField("authenticationHeaderProvider", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(finfo);
        dynamic sastoken = provider.GetType().InvokeMember("GetAuthorizationHeader", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, provider, null);
        if (client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization == null)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", sastoken);

        var jsontext = client.GetStringAsync("https://{yourNamespace}.azure-devices.net/twins/{yourDeviceId}?api-version=2018-04-01").Result;

        // log this jsontext

        var twin = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Twin>(jsontext);

        #endregion
```

use the above code snippet in your "bad" environment to see a json formatted text for your device.

Comment: Thanks let me test with this

Answer (score 0):

Although the DateTimeOffset structure provides a greater degree of time zone awareness than the DateTime structure, DateTime parameters are used more commonly in method calls. Because of this, the ability to convert DateTimeOffset values to DateTime values and vice versa is particularly important. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset).

I think you need to check the time zone setting in the different environments and the property value of the device twin.